# Binding Source Commit on DataSourceUpdateMode.Never

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have and object on

```
bindingSource.DataSource = object
```

I have to implement `Save` and `Revert Changes` on a Windows Form
for `Revert Changes` i have all Items for Properties with `DataSourceUpdateMode.Never`
and bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
-> works fine

but for `Save` I need to make a `Commit`
`bindingSource.EndEdit();` - it doesn't update my object

and i tried to make

```
TextEdit.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation;
bindingSource.EndEdit();
TextEdit.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never;
```

but it didn't work,
if i let DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation , the `Save` will work fine , but `Revert changes` will not work
and I don't want to make a copy of the object
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `DataSourceUpdateMode` enum to `Never` and use this method on several controls bound to the `BindingSource`, there are various problems:

```
it resets the values of other controls, or
it works for one control but not for the other.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.writevalue%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2006/10/10/Data-Binding-fails-me-again_2E002E002E00_.aspx